# How Can I Change [Array] or [Object] In My CLI Console Log To The Full Values?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

Currently, I am logging a variable to the test CLI, from which this is what I can view:

```
[
      [
        { Action: [Array], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: '*' },
        { Action: [Array], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: [Object] }
      ],
      [ { Action: [Array], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: '*' } ],
      [
        { Action: [Array], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: '*' },
        { Action: [Array], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: [Object] }
      ]
];
```

How can I change this, so instead of seeing `[Array]` or `[Object]`, I can see the full array or object?

Comment: Every console implementation is different. Node? Chrome? Firefox?

Comment: Node on the VsCode CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```js
const data = [
      [
        { Action: [1, 2, 3], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: '*' },
        { Action: [1, 2, 3], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: {a: 10} },
      ],
      [{ Action: [1, 2, 3], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: '*' }],
      [
        { Action: [1, 2, 3], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: '*' },
        { Action: [1, 2, 3], Effect: 'Allow', Resource: {a: 10} },
      ],
    ]
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```